# Redirecting to a page without displaying in browser ASP .NET/ WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to redirect to a new page from withing the controller of a webapi and not display the new address in the browser? If not what is the alternative?

Comment: iframes, but other than that - no. The whole point of a redirect is the user is supposed to know where they are going.

Comment: When you say redirect to a new page, what would the content returned by that URL be? Why not return the same content from your current controller/action?